# Tossing two dices with indications of $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Probability questions around $S=X+Y$.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, statistics, dice

**Exercise :**

> We toss two dices. Let $X$ be the indication of the result of the first one and $Y$ the indication of the result of the second one. If $S=X+Y$, find the following :
>
> (a) The probability mass function $p(s_j)$ of the random variable $S$.
>
> (b) The mean value $E[S]$ of the random variable $S$.
>
> (c) The variance $V[S]$ of the random variable $S$.

**Attempt :**

(a)

So, $S$ is the summation of the indications of the two dices, which means that the value of $S$ will rely in $[2,12]$, which is obvious. How would one continue to finding the probability mass function though ?

For (b) and (c), I do not know how to continue (I think you need (a) for those as well).

This is **not** a homework question, as it is an exam question which I'm trying to figure out in order for the upcoming semester tests. I would really appreciate any help on understanding the problem and the questions asked.

Comment: For a) the general method is called convolution. In this particular example when you adding two i.i.d. discrete uniform, you obtained a triangular distribution. For b) and c), you do not need to rely on the result of a). You just need to know how to calculate for individual dice and then sum them up (expectation is linear; by independence assumption there is no covariance term)

Comment: @BGM For (b) and (c) I will work through : $$E[X+Y] = E[X] + E[Y]$$ and $$V[S] = E[S^2]-E[S]^2$$ But how would I proceed in (a) though ? I didn't get it.

Comment: Concerning c) it is more handsome to follow the instruction of @BGM and to go for $V[S]=V[X]+V[Y]+Covar[X,Y]=V[X]+V[Y]$. Concerning (a) note that e.g. $P(S=5)=\sum_{k=1}^4P(X=k\wedge P(Y=5-k)=\sum_{k=1}^4P(X=k)P(Y=5-k)$ since $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: The way to visualize the counting: You make a $6$ by $6$ table, and write the support of $X, Y$ i.e. $1, 2, \ldots, 6$ on the two margins respectively. So each cell $(x, y)$ represent the event that $X = x, Y = y$ and by independence and uniform assumption, the probability of each happening is equally likely, i.e. $1/36$. Next, sum the coordinates and write it down for all the cells. Note the pattern appear on the table and count the number of cells with values $2, 3, \ldots 12$. Sum the corresponding probabilities (i.e. multiply the count by $1/36$ in this case) will be your required pmf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

The pdf of $X$ (or Y) is a uniform distribution on support set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ so the distribution of $S$ using convolution operator over its support set $\{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12\}$ is $$\dfrac{1}{36},\dfrac{2}{36},\dfrac{3}{36},\dfrac{4}{36},\dfrac{5}{36},\dfrac{6}{36},\dfrac{5}{36},\dfrac{4}{36},\dfrac{3}{36},\dfrac{2}{36},\dfrac{1}{36}$$Can you finish now?

Comment: This would imply that : $$p(s_j) = \frac{1}{36}$$ ?

Comment: What is $s_j$? It is a triangular distribution over the support set of $S$.

Comment: The probability mass function as described in the question form.

Comment: Yes....The numbers I wrote there are CDF values of $S$

Comment: IE . $~p(s_j) =\begin{cases} \frac 1{36} &:& s_j=2 \\ \frac 2{36} &:& s_j=3 \\ ~\vdots &\vdots &~ \vdots\end{cases}$

Comment: Yes that's right...

Comment: PDF, not CDF. $ $

Comment: [Checking that link here](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/104), seems like the correct answer is that the probability mass function is equal to $1/36$. I still don't get something here regarding the answer and everything people have written (which is not clear).